# merge output of mapreduce into another directory structure

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

My `mapreduce` job currently generates output using `multipleoutputs` ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820985/hadoop-method-to-send-output-to-multiple-directories)) in following structure:

```
2013
    01
    02
    ..

2012
    01
    02
    ..
```

The base path for the output is `/dev/project/job1/output`
However, another job(job2) generates similar data and I want the output of this job(job1) to merge with the output of the other job(job2).

I am trying to merge the generated output to a common output directory `(/dev/project/combinedoutput)` containing the above structure with a combined output of both jobs. Is there a way to do that with in the job itself with out manually running shell commands?

Appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the job itself? Not really, however you could do it in the main function after job completion

```
//prior code above

job.waitForCompletion(true);

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

String job1Dir = "/dev/project/job1/output";
String combinedDir = "(/dev/project/combinedoutput";

Path job1Path = new Path(job1Dir+*/);


FileStatus[] job1Files = fs.globStatus(job1Path);

for(file: job1Files){
    if(file.isFile()){
        String fullFileName = file.getPath().toString();
        String belowMainDir = fullFileName.subString(job1Dir.length());
        String newFileName = combinedDir+belowMainDir+"job1";
        fs.mkdirs(new Path(newFileName.subString(0,lastIndexOf("/")));
        fs.rename(file.getPath(),new Path(combinedDir+belowMainDir+"job1");
    }
}
```

This should get your files moved over. Do the same for job2 and you should be set. Optionally you could alter the code so that it will copy instead of rename, and/or so that it deletes the original job1/job2 directories after you finish.